# Python: Only saving three latest scores

Tags: python

This is my short quiz made for children. The main body of the program works fine. But it must save the three latest `correctAnswers` for each user onto a `.txt` file, deleting the old scores.

I've spent quite some time trying to work out how to use JSON or Pickle for my code but I have no idea how to use them for my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
if usersGroup == a:
    with open("groupA.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("\n{}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))

elif usersGroup == b:
    with open("groupB.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("\n{}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))

elif usersGroup == c:
    with open("groupC.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("\n{}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))
else:
    print("Sorry, we can not save your data as the group you entered is not valid.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite not append if you are updating the three scores at once:

```
open("groupA.txt","w")
```

To keep the last two from the previous run and write the latest single score:

```
with open("groupA.txt","a+") as f:
    sores = f.readlines()[-2:] # get last two previous lines
    with open("groupA.txt","w") as f:
        # write previous 2
        f.writelines(scores)
        # write latest
        f.write("\n{}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))
```

Might be easier pickle or json a dict and keep a list of scores replacing the last score with the latest.

```
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict

with open('scores.pickle', 'ab') as f:
    try:
        scores = pickle.load(f)
    except ValueError:
       scores = defaultdict(list) 

    # do your logic replacing last score for each name or adding names

   with open('scores.pickle', 'wb') as f:
       # pickle updated dict 
       pickle.dump(f,scores)
```

If you want human readable format use `json.dump` and a normal dict, you can use dict.setdefault instead of the functionality of using a defaultdict:

```
import json


with open('scores.json', 'a') as f:
    try:
        scores = json.load(f)
    except ValueError:
        scores = {}
        # add user if not already in the dict with a list as a value
        scores.setdefault(name,[])
         # just append the latest score making sure when you have three to relace the last
        scores[name].append(whatever)
 #   do your logic replacing last score for each name or adding names

    with open('scores.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(scores,f)
```

Comment: Ok  will edit so you just write one score each time yes?

Comment: well im hoping on the .txt file it says something like "(username): scored(correctAnswers),(correctAnswers),(correctAnswers)"          I might as well discard the timer for now

Comment: would the pickle code be on a new file or on my current code? Sorry if thats a stupid question. Im quite new to coding.

Comment: easiest thing to do  would be make a dict from your file contents  storing names as keys and appending each score then simply load and dump the dict accessing each user by name