# I want to add on a students score to a text file who has previously taken it

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
clas=(input("what class are you in?"))

if clas== 1:# this code works only if the users input is 1
    file= open("class1.txt", "a")# this creates a text file named class 1      which is created in the location of this program
    file.write(name) # this store/writes the users input to name into the text file
    file.write(str(score)) #this also stores the user score into the text file
    file.close()    # this close the file after the data has been saved

elif clas==2:# this code works only if the inputs 2 as thier clas
    file= open("class2.txt","a")# this creates a text file named class2 which is created in the location of this program
    file.write(name)# this store/writes the users input to name into the text file
    file.write(str(score))
    file.close()
elif clas==3:# this code works if the user inputs 3 as thier clas

    file= open("class3.txt","a")# this creates a text file named class3 which is created in the location of this program
    file.write(name)
    file.write(str(score))# this store/writes the users input to name into the text file
    file.close()# this close the file after the data has been saved
```

This is a section of my code, i want to add more scores(up to 3) to the same line. for example

john,10  - this is what my code does

john,10,9,2 this is what i want it to do

i also would like help knowing how i can add scores to the same line if the same persons does the maths quiz. thanks

Comment: You really should be using `raw_input` here. Also you can remove all the duplication in the case statements by using string operations to select the filename. Also use the context managers for opening files, it keeps things a lot cleaner.

Comment: Use a dict and json.dump/load, a txt file is not a good structure for what you want, somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308840/python-only-saving-three-latest-scores/28308870#28308870

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a list of scores somewhere like so:

```
scores = [10, 9, 2]
```

You could make your code look like this:

```
def write_score_to_file(name, file_number, scores):
    file= open("class{0}.txt".format(file_number), "a")
    file.write("{0}, ".format(name))
    file.write(", ".join([str(s) for s in scores]))
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()

clas = str(input("what class are you in?"))
write_score_to_file("John", clas, scores)
```

Comment: Gotta love the downvotes with no comment. (Even though this code works, does what the op wanted, and shows a better way of organising his code...)